# GeoServer GeoTIFF not displayed on map as long as not edited

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have the problem that GeoTIFF files are not displayed on map using GeoServer 2.22.5 while the same file is visible using GeoServer 2.11.0.

By chance, however, I realised that the image on the map suddenly becomes visible if changing the file (here: simply draw a line via Paint.NET) and save it.
Here is the comparison using gdalinfo (the original file on the left, the modified and saved file on the right)

[image]

Ok, so the workaround would be to open and save all files in order to make them visible, but I dont't understand the real problem and why GeoServer 2.22.5 displays nothing when using the original file.

What is the real problem here and what would be the solution for this?

Comment: Please add the gdalinfo output as text not as pictures

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this:
Changing the following part of the depending SLD-file solved the problem:

Not working:

```
...
<sld:ColorMap>
 <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#000000" opacity="0.0" quantity="0.0"/>
 <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#0F0F0F" opacity="1.0" quantity="1.0"/>
 <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#0F0F0F" opacity="1.0" quantity="254.0"/>
 <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#000000" opacity="0.0" quantity="255.0"/>
</sld:ColorMap>
...
```

Working:

```
...
<sld:ColorMap>
  <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#000000" opacity="0.0" quantity="0.0"/>
  <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#0F0F0F" opacity="1.0" quantity="1.0"/>
</sld:ColorMap>
...
```